# Merge two rows in one SQL Server table

Tags: sql-server

I want to merge two rows. I use the following SQL query

```
SELECT
    StoreName, Cateagory, ItemName, 
    SUM(Qty) AS Qty, Rate,
    SUM(Purchage) AS Purchage,
    p_Rate, SUM(S_Qty) AS S_Qty, S_Rate 
FROM 
    Stock 
GROUP BY
    StoreName, Category, ItemName, Rate, p_Rate, S_Rate        
ORDER BY 
    StoreName ASC
```

But it's not working properly.

Please see the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Well, for starters, you have half your code commented out with '--'

Comment: It should be **category** (not "catagory")

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell what columns determine a unique field, but I'll guess that you only want to be grouping by `StoreName`, `Category`, and `ItemName`. For the other fields, I added in `MAX` aggregate functions to get the non-zero values.

```
SELECT
    StoreName,
    Catagory,
    ItemName,
    SUM(Qty) AS Qty,
    MAX(Rate),
    SUM(Purchage) AS Purchage,
    MAX(p_Rate),
    SUM(S_Qty) AS S_Qty,
    MAX(S_Rate) 
FROM Stock 
GROUP BY StoreName, Catagory, ItemName        
ORDER BY StoreName ASC
```